# Postgres delete a row if the foreign key's column is set to false

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have table 1 like so:

Template table:

```
ID              int    
Name            string 
TemplateGroupID int
```

Template_group table:

```
ID              int    
Name            string 
IsDefault       bool
```

I would like to delete a row in template, if that row's FK to template_group column `IsDefault` is set to true. How can I do that? I was thinking it was something like this:

```
delete from template 
where id =33 and exists (
    select * from template_group where is_default = true
);
```

But I don't think that is correct because don't I have to select the `TemplateGroupId` in the subselect?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Postgres' `delete ... from ... using ... where ...` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-delete.html):

```
delete 
from template t  
using template_group g 
where g.ID = t.TemplateGroupID and g.IsDefault = true
```

Answer (score 2):

You need another condition in the WHERE clause:

```
delete from template t 
where t.id = 33 
and exists (
  select * 
  from template_group 
  where id = t.TemplateGroupID and is_default = true
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need is this sql :

```
delete from template 
where  templategroupid in 
(select id from template_group where isdefault = true);
```

ps : I wrote all words with consonant, because even if you wrote vowel Postgresql convert them to consonant.